# Can not run react-js app, events.js:291 throw er; Unhandled 'error'

Tags: reactjs

I got the below error when I run a react-app on a computer. I have tried to below ways but still not able to run.

- Delete `node_modules` and run `npm install` again
- Create a new application
- Reinstall Nodejs
- Restart computer
- Copy a project (which work well) from another computer
- Add `%SystemRoot%\system32` to `Enviroment Path`

[image]

Here is the log inside `2020-07-03T08_45_12_940Z-debug`

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\van.mai21\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v14.5.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle my_first_app@0.1.0~prestart: my_first_app@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle my_first_app@0.1.0~start: my_first_app@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle my_first_app@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle my_first_app@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\van.mai21\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\ReactJS\my_first_app\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;"C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin";C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin;D:\projects\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\xampp\php;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\van.mai21\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\van.mai21\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\van.mai21\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle my_first_app@0.1.0~start: CWD: D:\ReactJS\my_first_app
10 silly lifecycle my_first_app@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle my_first_app@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle my_first_app@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: my_first_app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\van.mai21\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\van.mai21\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid my_first_app@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd D:\ReactJS\my_first_app
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\van.mai21\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v14.5.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.5
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error my_first_app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the my_first_app@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Computer: Window 10, 64 bit. Nodejs: 12.18.2/14.5.0
Any help or suggestion to fix this problem would be great appreciated.

Comment: I end up by recovery my Window 10. It take time but it easy. My reactjs app working well now.

Comment: this is happened  to me too, any update from you op?

Comment: I can not solve problem so I do like my previous comment